# Retrieving a function of many complex variables from its manifold of zeros

Tags: algebraic-geometry, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, several-complex-variables

Physical background:

In the Bargmann-Segal representation, the states of bosonic quantum systems are holomorphic functions of $N$ complex variables where $N$ is the number of degrees of freedom. The states belong to a Hilbert space with the scalar product defined with the help of the measure $\exp(-\sum_{i}{z_{i}^{\star} z_{i}}) d z_{1}... d z_{N}$.

Now, the question is: is it possible to retrieve a quantum state from its nodes? That is, is it possible to retrieve a holomorphic (entire) function of $N$ variables from its manifold of zeros?

As far as I understand, in the case  of $N = 1$ we have the Weierstrass factorization theorem which gives a positive answer. So, does there exist a generalization of that theorem to $N > 1$?

To be even more ambitious: let us suppose we have a curve in $\Bbb R^{3}$, a torus knot, say. Given the information that it is an intersection of a complex curve $K$ with a sphere, and the form of the knot, can we retrieve the entire function $f(z_{1}, z_{2})$ such that $f(z_{1}, z_{2}) = 0$ is an equation of $K$?

I apologize if the question is naive, and imprecise; I'm a physicist, not a mathematician. And thank you for your attention.

Comment: What do you mean retrieve it from ? Because in the $N=1$ case, Weierstrass factorization doesn't give back the function, it gives *a* function with the correct zeroes

Comment: To add to Max's comment, in $N=1$, if you are given the zeros together with multiplicities, you can recover the function up to multiplication by $e^{g(z)}$, where $g$ is an arbitrary holomorphic function.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable comments. In particular, many thanks to Wojowu for reminding me about the exponential factor. But I think the question remains valid if I replace "the" with "a". To repeat, is there a(!) generalization of the Weierstrass factorization theorem to several complex variables? And, what about getting a(!) complex curve from its knot in ${\bf R^{3}}$? If you tell me that it is a simple exercise I should do on my own, I'll accept this as a legitimate answer, provided that you give me some hints. With best regards, Hau Hau

Comment: I would also like to thank jgon and YuiTo Cheng for their great editorial work.